# What does DexClassLoader expect as input for libraryPath?

Tags: android

The DexClassLoader contructor looks like this:

```
public DexClassLoader (String dexPath, String optimizedDirectory, String libraryPath, ClassLoader parent)
```

What does `DexClassLoader` expect to be passed for libraryPath (besides `null`)?

Is it possible to pass in an external library as a parameter to DexClassLoader? If so does the libraryPath parameter behave similar to java's `-classpath cmd` line option? I wrote a simple java application that references a jar file as an external library, now I want to replicate the behavior in an android app.

I have a jar with math functions: MyMath.jar - contains a class "Add" and a method "add". In my main program I import the "mymath" package from MyMath.jar, create an instance of the Add class and call its add method.

To build I use:
*javac -classpath ../lib/MyMath.jar MainProgram.java*

To run I use:
*java -classpath .;../lib/MyMath.jar MainProgram*

This successfully utilizes the MyMath.jar to access the "`Add`" class in my main program. Now I need to replicate this in an android app, but I am unable to successfully load MyMath.jar with DexClassLoader, here is my implementation:

```
DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader("/storage/sdcard/Download/MainProgram.jar", codeCacheDir.getAbsolutePath(), "/storage/sdcard/Download/MyMath.jar", ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

I can instantiate classes and invoke its methods that do not depend on "MyMath.jar" with classloader, but I cannot invoke methods that do depend on MyMath.jar

Here's the thrown exception when I try to invoke a method that depends on MyMath.jar:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mymath/Add;
   ...
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mymath.Add" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/storage/sdcard/Download/MainProgram.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

---

How can I link MyMath.jar library when I load MainProgram.jar using DexClassLoader?

Comment: DexClassLoader can't load jvm classes from jars.  In fact, there is no mechanism in Android to load jvm classes.  Android apps require classes converted to dalvik and bundled into a dex file.

Comment: I've already converted both my jar files to dalvik executable format using "dx --dex --output ./dexJar.jar ./orig.jar" and I am able to access, instantiate, and invoke methods from my jar files. My question is how can I link libraries when I use DexClassLoader?

Answer (score 0):

This library might help: https://github.com/simpleton/dalvik_patch/blob/master/inject_secondary_dex/src/com/example/dex/DexInjector.java

First, you can turn your jar file to dex file, by

```
dx --dex --output ./MyMath_dex.jar ./MyMath.jar
```

And then, you can load your dex file in Android, for more information, you can read the source code in library above.

Answer (score 0):

DexClassLoader's first parameter takes in "**list** of jar/apk files containing classes and **resources**, delimited by File.pathSeparator, which defaults to ":" on Android"

The solution was to simply concatenate my MyMath.jar to my MainProgram.jar:

```
final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(
"/storage/sdcard/Download/MainProgram.jar" + ":" +
"/storage/sdcard/Download/MyMath.jar", 
codeCacheDir.getAbsolutePath(),
null,
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```